# Centering Text within a Multirow Cell in LaTex

Tags: alignment, latex, multirow

This is probably best explained with an example. I have the following table, where the "A" cell spans two rows, and the "B" cell spans two columns.

```
\begin{table}[htdp]
\begin{tabular}{l|r|r}
\multirow{2}{*}{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{B} \\
  & B1 & B2 \\
a & b1 & b2 \\
a & b1 & b2 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
|A      |_ _ _ _B_ _ _ _|
|_ _ _ _|_ _B1_ |_ _B2_ |
|a      |     b1|     b2|
|a      |     b1|     b2|
|a      |     b1|     b2|
|_ _ _ _| _ _ _ |_ _ _ _|
```

I would like to center the text in the "A" cell, only. I would like to leave the rest of the column left-aligned. Giving:

```
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
|   A   |_ _ _ _B_ _ _ _|
|_ _ _ _|_ _B1_ |_ _B2_ |
|a      |     b1|     b2|
|a      |     b1|     b2|
|a      |     b1|     b2|
|_ _ _ _| _ _ _ |_ _ _ _|
```

I'm sure this must be simple to do, but I can't seem to put my finger on it.

Comment: Thanks for a clear example of what you wanted to accomplish, by the way!

Comment: Thanks, Dave :-)   I was wondering whether I might be stating the obvious a little with the second table, but I felt one can't make things too clear.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I *think* you need to do that with a fake `\multicolumn`:

```
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{A}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}B} \\
```

Inspiration from [this FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=multirow).

Comment: That gives: ! Misplaced \omit. \multispan -> \omit \@multispan. Not sure what that means :-S

Comment: Try swapping the nesting of the multirow/multicolumn? (so the multicolumn is on the outside). Sorry, I haven't got a working LaTeX install here to play with!

Comment: Edited answer to put multirow inside multicolumn instead of the other way round -- sorry, I think I got the nesting backwards!

Answer (score 16):

I came across a similar problem, but had to use `\multirow{specified width}{}` instead of `\multirow{*}{}`. Nesting multirow inside a multicolumn does not work in this case.

I found `\multirow{specified width}{\centering text}` to work instead.

Comment: This works particularly well if you are trying to center-align text over multiple rows, whereas the other solution only aligns the entire block. Thanks :)

Comment: I think you have the arguments in the wrong order. nrows is before width, right?

Answer (score 7):

```
\multirow{2}{*}{\hfil A}
```

`\hfil` will automatically calculate the width of the cell and insert a half-width space

To insert a full cell-width space, which will right-justify a single cell, use `\hfill`.
There are also `\vfil` and `\vfill` analogues.

Comment: It does the trick in the easiest way. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That is could be helpful for someone

```
\begin{tabular}{|c c | c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Modulation}} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{M} \\
\cline{3-5}
&  & 2  & 4 & 8 \\
\hline
   \multirow{3}*{\hfil SNR=$\begin{cases}  \\  \\  \end{cases}$}    &  STMA &  xx dB & xx dB & xx dB\\
      &  QTMA    & xx dB & xx dB & xx dB \\
      &  POSTMA & xx dB & xx dB & xx dB\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```