# Is it possible to vertically center multiple columns in a table?

Tags: alignment, latex, multiple-columns, multirow

I've found an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910478/centering-text-within-a-multirow-cell-in-latex) but that only centers one column and I can't really adapt it to my needs. What I'd like is something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You'll need `\usepackage{array}` to do this.

From what I can gather, you're looking at the `m{}` alignment, which wraps a paragraph at the specified point value, and vertically aligns the text to the middle of the field.  For example, something like this:

```
\begin{tabular}{|m{2cm}|m{1ex}|m{1ex}|m{1ex}} \hline
           & x1 & x2 & x3 \\\hline
Long Label & 1  & 0  & 1  \\\hline
Long Label & 0  & 1  & 1  \\\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: i can't get it to compile like that. i've tried searching for that array package before too because i read about it after searching on google, but i couldn't find its documentation

Comment: I'm a dolt.  It's \usepackage{array}, not \include{array}.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I'm going to tinker around with it for a bit until LaTeX agrees with what I'm saying.

Comment: I forgot to add an extra alignment.  So the top line should have 1 m{2cm} and 3 m{1ex}.  I left out one of the m{1ex}

Comment: i compiled it and it doesn't work as intended. the text in the x1/x2/x3 columns aren't centered vertically

Comment: THANK YOU!   This is by far the simplest solution I've seen, and the only one's that's worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
\begin{tabular}{|m{3.5em}|b{1em}|b{1em}|b{1em}|}
\hline
%% row 1

&x1
&x2
&x3
\\\hline
%% row 2
Long Label
&1
&0
&1
\\\hline
%% row 3
Long Label
&1
&0
&1
\\\hline
\end{tabular}
```

For more info on table formatting see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables

EDIT: changed c to b{}

Comment: that's not really centering the text vertically

Comment: I don't know what that even means - it is centre aligned... if you are referring to wrapping, then you need to set the column size by using m{} instead of c

Comment: you're using the |c| to center the text horizontally, not vertically. look at the image i posted. i want to align the text in multiple columns so that it is centered according to the first one, which takes multiple rows. if you know how to use the m{} command, could you post an example?

Comment: visit the wikibook I listed, you will get all you need from there

Comment: This might be a better question for tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: it isn't there. in the example given in the "Spanning in both directions simultaneously" section it only has the same thing as in the question i linked in the op. seems this just isn't possible with latex since i can't find examples with it anywhere

Comment: well, using b{} instead of m{} did align it vertically but now it isn't horizontally aligned... argh!

Comment: then you need booktabs package, here's the documentation: http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf

Comment: none of the examples in the documentation do what i need, and pretty much all of google's results point to it with at most examples taken from the documentation