# Text alignment on top with multirow command

Tags: alignment, latex, multirow

I have a problem with the following code:

```
\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \caption{Titel}
  \resizebox{.95\columnwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{p{4.5cm}p{10cm}p{3.5cm}}
        \hline
        Name & \multicolumn{2}{p{\textwidth-3\tabcolsep-\widthof{test}-2\fboxrule}}
            {long_title which goes over two coloums}\\
        \hline
        Explanation & \multicolumn{2}{p{\textwidth-3\tabcolsep-\widthof{test}-2\fboxrule}}
            {Explanation which goes over two coloums}\\
        \hline
        \multirow{3}{*}{Targets} 
            & Target 1 is long text with two lines & not reached\\
        \cline{2-3}
        & Target 2 & reached\\
        \cline{2-3}
        & Target 3 & reached\\
        \hline

    \end{tabular}%
    }
  \label{tab:test}%
\end{table}%
```

I hope this photo helps to understand my problem:

[image: Problem Example]

I would like to align the text "Targets" on the top of the cell, like the second table. I'm sure this must be simple to do, but I can't seem to put my finger on it. Please help me with this alignment.

Comment: Do i have to use something else than the "*" ?

Comment: This seems like the opposite of your problem, it may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910478/centering-text-within-a-multirow-cell-in-latex

Comment: sorry but i don't know how to adpat, i try to use vfill and centering both dont work

Comment: flagged as a duplicate of your previous question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583310/text-alignment-on-top-with-multirow-command

Answer (score 1):

Instead of specifying the widths of the columns explicitly use the `l` specifier (which may require the array package). An example of its usage would be the following

```
\begin{center}
     \begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | p{5cm} |}
     \hline
     Day & Min Temp & Max Temp & Summary \\ \hline
     Monday & 11C & 22C & A clear day with lots of sunshine.  
     However, the strong breeze will bring down the temperatures. \\ \hline
     Tuesday & 9C & 19C & Cloudy with rain, across many northern regions. Clear spells
     across most of Scotland and Northern Ireland,
     but rain reaching the far northwest. \\ \hline
     Wednesday & 10C & 21C & Rain will still linger for the morning.
     Conditions will improve by early afternoon and continue
     throughout the evening. \\
     \hline
     \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

this will provide an output like this

[image: Example]

Note the top alignment of all columns.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for the try, but there is a reason why i have the widths